# Widget marker and tilt map on mapbox_gl?

Tags: flutter, mapbox, mapbox-gl, fluttermap

I see it's possible to have a widget as a marker when we use FlutterMap. But we can't "tilt" the map (to give a 3D effect).
In my project, I would like to be able to tilt the map by 90.0 degrees (set in CameraPosition() ) and to be able to have a widget as marker (like in FlutterMap()).

Any ideas?